# How to force text to wrap inside inline-block div?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a horizontal scrollable list in Ionic.
I don't understand why, but following solution arranges child items horizontaly only with `white-space: nowrap;`
I believe, because of that text below the images in the list is not wrapping.
How to make it correctly and set text width equal to image width?

[image: You can see that text under images is freaking out]

CSS code:

```
.wide-as-needed {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
}
```

HTML code:

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" class="wide-as-needed" has-bouncing="true">
              <div ng-repeat="book in books" style="margin:10px;display: inline-block;"> 
           <img ng-src="{{book.cover || './img/noCover.png'}}" err-src="./img/noCover.png" alt="{{book.title}}"/>
                <div style="max-width: 10em;">
                  <ul>
                   <li>{{book.title}}</li>
                    <li> {{book.author}}</li>
                  </ul>              
                </div>    
            </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Comment: restore `white-space: normal;` inside the inner div elements

Comment: thanks Fabrizio. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  margin: 25px;
}
.wrapper .caption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: darkgrey;
  padding: .25em
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-250-250-3.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, debitis!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working... Items inside <ion-scroll> stacked vertically. Looks like this: http://bit.ly/1H0XJYL

Comment: The you really need to make a working demo using the output HTML & CSS. Otherwise we can't diagnose what is going wrong.

Comment: I was wrong. After some tuning and experiments and by combining your solution with displayL inline-block it  finally works!